# Short story; invasion by timelike aliens averted by a handy native fixing their ship

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Trying to find a short science fiction story  where an alien race arrives from a parallel time world which is not spacelike but timelike. They are stuck in a valley and need someone from a near village to help fix their stranded spaceship and have intentions of conquering our spatial universe. A local lad with "golden" hands fixes it in a manner which eliminates their intention of conquering this world. He sends them as I recall "perhaps mañana".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

["Like a Bird, Like a Fish"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?69068), a short story by [H. B. Hickey](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?1840), first published in [*Worlds Beyond*, February 1951](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?62276+c), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Worlds_Beyond_v01n03_1951-02_cape1736#page/n41/mode/1up); reprinted in the anthology [*Worlds of Tomorrow*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?34631) edited by [August Derleth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/August_Derleth).

Plot summary from [www.storypilot.com](https://www.storypilot.com/tt.php?keywords=hickey):

> When a strange ship crashes in Guadalajara, the villagers call Father Vincent. When the priest realizes that the visitors are lost and their ship is broken, he calls Pablo, who can fix anything (although generally mañana). And when everyone realizes that the visitors, who have already conquered their own realm where time-is-space and vice versa, mean to conquer Earth next (after all, Earthlings make good food), it seems too late to call anyone.

**Trying to find a short science fiction story where an alien race arrives from a parallel time world which is not spacelike but timelike.**

> "In the name of our Lord, what are you?" he demanded.
>
> There was no reply.
>
> "From where do you come?" he asked.
>
> He could feel something probing at his mind, feeling around his question. *Where are you from?* In his mind were all the possibilities, all the seas and the continents and the planets. And beyond those the galaxies and the universes.
>
> The thing that probed his mind rejected all the possibilities there.
>
> "Not *where*, came the thought. "*When*."
>
> "When?"
>
> "Yesterday."
>
> "I do not understand," the priest said.
>
> "This is the world of space," the thought came. "You live in the world of space, of places. In moving across space, you create time.
>
> "We live in the world of time. We move across time to create space."
>
> "I do not understand."
>
> "No matter. Your *yesterday* and our *now* lie across each other. The machine brought us through the wall."
>
> *There is no end to God's wonders*, the priest thought. "Welcome," he said aloud.
>
> "At what point in space are we?" came the question. "Where?"
>
> "In our world. In Mexico. In a far corner of Guadalajara. It is a simple village, and I am Father Vincent, the priest."

**They are stuck in a valley and need someone from a near village to help fix their stranded spaceship**

> "Our machine does not move through your space," the thought came. "According to our theory it should function, but it does not. We entered space and found ourselves here. Now we cannot move."
>
> "Obviously something is broken, or not working properly," the priest said. He knew Latin and several other languages and a goodly amount of astronomy, but mechanical things were a mystery to him.

**and have intentions of conquering our spatial universe.**

> And then, because they could see in his mind that thee were no weapons Earth could use against them, they told him how they had conquered their stratum of time, and let him see the manner in which they had done it.
>
> And finally, with nothing left to conquer, they had turned their minds outside their own world. One of them, such as would be called a scientist, had theorized that a spatial world must exist, and that it would be a coefficient of their time world. So the machine had been built.
>
> Now that the experiment had proved successful, and as soon as they could move through space also, they would go back and build machines.
>
> Father Vincent was sorry that the villagers had called him. They should have set the fire. But it was too late.
>
> "You will come in peace?" he asked, his voice beginning to tremble. "You will do no harm?"
>
> But he knew the question was futile. They would come to Earth as they had come to all of their own world.

**A local lad with "golden" hands fixes it**

> And he told them about Pablo. How since Pablo was a boy he had this wonderful gift; how he had been able to repair the first automobile he had ever seen; how without training he had been able to take a fine watch apart, fashion replacement parts and make it work better than new. In short, how Pablo could make anything work, no matter how simple or complex.
>
> "It is as if his untrained mind sees into the very soul of mechanical things. No, never fear. Simply tell Pablo how it is *supposed* to work, and he will make it do so."

**in a manner which eliminates their intention of conquering this world. He sends them as I recall "perhaps mañana"**

> He sighed. "So. Thus with the machine. Before, it could fly through their Time, but not through our Space. Now it is fixed so it flies through Space."
>
> "But still through Time also!" the priest said. "It vanished!"
>
> "A bird dives *into* the water too," Pablo reminded him. "But that does not mean it will swim."
>
> He sighed again. "What part of Time were they from, Padre?"
>
> "Yesterday," Father Vincent said.
>
> "I do not think they will reach yesterday. Maybe tomorrow, but not yesterday." Pablo laughed. "Yes, maybe mañana."

Comment: Thank you user14111. This is indeed the story I enjoyed very much.